# Using Java "this" keyword in a class that implements and extends other classes

Tags: java, oop, this

So I am trying to understand the "this" keyword in details. 
I understand that the "this" keyword refers to the current object. The object whose method or constructor is being called.

So when I use for example "this.setLayout", will it search for the object that thas the method "setLayout"?

Let's say, I extend a class and implement other classes in my super class. If I use "this", will it search for the method in all the implemented and extended classes?

For example my class:

`public class GUI extends JPanel implements Runnable, ActionListener`

and I use:

`this.setLayout();`

So this means, the complier will search for the method "setLayout" in all the extended and implemented classes, until it finds the method in Jpanel?

I just want to understand how "this" knows what I am trying to do.

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see if it finds the method? Would have been faster to try it out than it was to write this question.

Comment: Yes, `this` means it searches first in your object, then if it doesn't find a method/field, it will search up the hierarchy until it reaches `Object`.  If no method is found by then, it throws an error.

Comment: Also, "searches" and message dispatch are old terms.  They're sometimes useful, but most modern compilers know on class load time what methods each class implements, so there's no real "search" to take place.

Comment: I'd recommend finding a well-loved Java book, like one by Deitel and Deitel, and reading it closely.  It'll save you a lot of time and confusion.

Comment: Here's a quick tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html  I personally was never fond of the Deitel books, they all seemed perfunctorily written by grad students.  I'd recommend O'Reily's *Learning Java*, but it's not an absolute beginner's book, so try to investigate it a bit first to see if it's useful to you.

Comment: @markspace The is a *search* taking place in the compiler. The JLS even calls it a search: [15.12.1. Compile-Time Step 1: Determine Class or Interface to **Search**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)

Comment: _"So this means, the complier will search for the method "setLayout" in all the extended and implemented classes, until it finds the method in Jpanel?"_ -- not quite. It only searches the class hierarchy above your object, and will find the method in `JPanel` only if your object extends `JPanel` or one of `JPanel`'s subclasses.

Comment: Well that question sounds like differnce of "this" in tree based/ai languages like Lisp or Javascript on the one hand and Java on the other. Java is a by far simpler/less powerfull language(which makes it more straight forward on the other hand) than those AI languages.  So "this" is just the object the method was defined in(as the method cant be assigned to different objects and reparenting and rebinding and alike is not possible). So you don't have to search. It's simply a static reverence.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah that's fair.  Just as long as we're clear that it is compile time when this happens, and not so much run time and almost never per method invocation.

Comment: @kai It *is* a search for the method in the current class, its super classes, and all its interfaces. The *result* of the search is that the compiler generates a statically bound method call, but the compiler still has to do a *search* for the method declaration. The question specifically asks if "the compiler will search". It's not asking about searching at runtime.

Comment: You implement **interfaces**, not classes!

Comment: @andreas: noesense. it is the reference(!) that points to the instance(!) you used when invoking. Wich is in contrast to tree based where it could be eg. the object from which you are invoking or  anything you like to point it to(binding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"This" means the object you are currently on. If method setLayout() is not overridden, "this" will search in every extended class since GUI includes every method of them

Comment: And if `setLayout()` *is* overridden? Same thing. Method overriding has nothing to do with it.

Comment: If the method is overridden, there is no need to search the extended classes.

Comment: If the method is locally declared, overriding another method or not, there is no need to search the super classes. As I said, *overriding* has nothing to do with it. Saying that overriding affects the search is just muddling the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does that mean if I initialise an obejct of another class in the same package, and I import classes from other libraries, "this" will search in all of these if the object is initialised ?  So basically "this" will search in all the implemented, extended classes, as well as in all initialised obejcts within the class?

Comment: It will search your class and if it doesn't find anything, it will search super ones. Implements doesn't work like that since every method into an interface is bare and must be included by you, in your own class

Comment: And what if I have two or more instances of an object? For example JPanel panel1, panel2 etc. In this case using "this" would be confusing.

Comment: It's gonna refer to the sub-class, the overridden one.